# Reduce array of objects for same key values by perserving the data(pushing the values in an array) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, lodash

I have data in the following format basically an array of objects, I have tried several approaches, how can I do it more effectively?

```
const overdue =  [
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10001440",
            "objectives": [
                "Understand the financial indexes."
            ]
        },
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10000303",
            "objectives": [
                "Document preparation & writing skills"
            ]
        },
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10002168",
            "objectives": [
                "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11"
            ]
        },

        {
            "user.employeeId": "10002168",
            "objectives": [
                "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization"
            ]
        },
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10002168",
            "objectives": [
                "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization"
            ]
        },
    ]
```

How do I convert it into the following by JavaScript using lodash??

```
[
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10001440",
            "objectives": [
                "Understand the financial indexs."
            ]
        },
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10000303",
            "objectives": [
                "Document preparation & writing skills"
            ]
        },
        {
            "user.employeeId": "10002168",
            "objectives": [
                "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization",
                "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization",
                "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have tried with Array.map! and normal logic, how can we do it more efficiently using lodash reduce or arr.reduce?

Comment: You want to merge the objectives for an employee into one object, but leave the others out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve the desired result, using an array as the accumulator.

We enumerate each object in the *overdue* array, if it is not present in the output array we add it, otherwise we add the object objectives to the relevant element in the output.

```js
const overdue =  [ { "user.employeeId": "10001440", "objectives": [ "Understand the financial indexes." ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10000303", "objectives": [ "Document preparation & writing skills" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization" ] }, ]; 

let result = overdue.reduce((res, row) => {
    let el = res.find(el => el["user.employeeId"] === row["user.employeeId"]);
    // If we find the object in the output array simply update the objectives
    if (el) {
       el.objectives = [...el.objectives, ...row.objectives];
    } else {
    // If we _don't_ find the object, add to the output array.
      res.push({ ...row});
    }
    return res;
}, [])

console.log("Result:",result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `array.reduce` and pass an object to the accumulator. In the callback function check if the accumulator have a key same as value of `user.employeeId`. If not then create the key and add the current object under iteration as its value. If already have a key then just update the objectives array. While retrieving the value is `Object.value` which will give an array

```js
const overdue = [{
    "user.employeeId": "10001440",
    "objectives": [
      "Understand the financial indexes."
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10000303",
    "objectives": [
      "Document preparation & writing skills"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11"
    ]
  },

  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization"
    ]
  },
];



let newData = overdue.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!acc[curr['user.employeeId']]) {
    acc[curr['user.employeeId']] = curr;
  } else {
    curr.objectives.forEach((item) => {
      acc[curr['user.employeeId']]['objectives'].push(item)
    })
  }
  return acc;
}, {});


console.log(Object.values(newData))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how to do it in lodash, but here is how I would do it using only vanilla Javascript:

```js
const overdue = [{
    "user.employeeId": "10001440",
    "objectives": [
      "Understand the financial indexes."
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10000303",
    "objectives": [
      "Document preparation & writing skills"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11"
    ]
  },

  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization"
    ]
  },
  {
    "user.employeeId": "10002168",
    "objectives": [
      "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization"
    ]
  },
];

const combined = {};

overdue.forEach(o => {
  const id = o["user.employeeId"];
  const obj = o["objectives"][0];
  
  if(!combined[id]) { combined[id] = [obj]; }
  else { combined[id].push(obj); }
  
});

const result = [];

Object.keys(combined).forEach(key => {
  result.push({"user.employeeId" : key, "objectives" : combined[key]});
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lodash then you can go beyond reduce and use something more specific for your needs. In this can, you could consider use the [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) method, which will create an object keyed by the `user.employeeId` values, containing values as arrays of each object. You can then [map the values](https://lodash.com/docs/#mapValues) of your object (ie: an array of objects with the same employeeId), to a [merged object](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) where each `objectives` array is merged. Lastly, you can get the values of your grouped object to get your result:

```js
const overdue = [{ "user.employeeId": "10001440", "objectives": [ "Understand the financial indexes." ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10000303", "objectives": [ "Document preparation & writing skills" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization" ] }, ];

const group = _.flow(
  arr => _.groupBy(arr, "user.employeeId"),
  g => _.mapValues(g, arr => _.mergeWith(...arr, (objV, srcV) => {
    if (_.isArray(objV)) return objV.concat(srcV);
  })),
  _.values
);

console.log(group(overdue));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use vanilla JS with `.reduce()` with a `Map`, this uses more modern features of JS (both supported in node 14.0.0) such as [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` and the [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??`:

```js
const overdue = [{ "user.employeeId": "10001440", "objectives": [ "Understand the financial indexes." ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10000303", "objectives": [ "Document preparation & writing skills" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Chia ratio setting for Fuze Tea products L11" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Brix parameter differences between Processing and Production of Fuze Tea Lemon-Lemongrass standardization" ] }, { "user.employeeId": "10002168", "objectives": [ "Paramix Line 9 setting parameter standardization" ] }, ];

const group = (arr, key) => Array.from(arr.reduce((m, obj) =>
  m.set(
    obj[key], 
    {...obj, objectives: [...(m.get(obj[key])?.objectives ?? []), ...obj.objectives]}
  ), new Map).values()
);

console.log(group(overdue, "user.employeeId"));
```